# Trying to get an alert if three seperate cells do not match

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, alert, worksheet-function

Hi  I am trying to put 2 formulas together in one cell

The first is to give a sum, i.e. :  =(D3+F3+H3+J3)-(C3+E3+G3+I3)

The second is to check the resulting number above against a number total in 2 other cells with similar sum formulas and then alert or change colour of cell if any of the three are not the same number.

Can anyone assit?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

(Note: Instructions and screenshot from Excel 2013 but should apply to Excel 2010)

Let's assume the cell with your formula is C4 and the "two other cells" are C5 and C6.

1. Enter your formula in cell C4
2. With cell C4 selected, go to Conditional Formatting -> New rule...

   - Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`
   - Enter the formula as shown below
   - Press the `Format...` button and select the highlighting you want(eg white text on red background)
   - Press the `OK` button to apply the conditional format.

[image: Screenshot of Excel 2013]

Comment: Cute trick, comparing the `MIN` to the `MAX`. I'll have to try to remember that.